# Strange warnings logged when running Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting the following logged in console when running `rails test`.

```
❯ rails test
Running 55 tests in parallel using 8 processes
DEBUGGER: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1387
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1388]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1388
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1389]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1389
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1390]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1390
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1392]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1392
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1391]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1391
Run options: --seed 17238

# Running:

DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1393]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1393
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#1394]: Attaching after process 1372 fork to child process 1394
.......................................................

Finished in 0.508849s, 108.0871 runs/s, 178.8350 assertions/s.
55 runs, 91 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

This doesn't happen when the number of tests is below a certain number. Doesn't seem to cause any problems, just annoying.

Comment: Maybe you've got some IDE running that automagically attaches a debugger to rails processes? The reason you are seeing this multiple times, is because you are running tests in parallel.

Comment: Those debug logs are not a standard feature in ruby/rails; you must be using some custom code/library to trigger it. My **guess** is that it's got something to do with [the `debug` gem](https://github.com/ruby/debug). Are you using that?

Comment: For example, I see the same error message as your question in the source code here: https://github.com/ruby/debug/blob/3571a19cf28e8b9ec24cb190a42bb67620a20bf7/lib/debug/session.rb#L2097

Comment: Note: The log messages are because you are running tests in parallel, which is a nice feature to make the total suite of tests run much faster. When you only run a small number of tests, I suppose rails doesn't bother parallelising them - and that's why you don't see this log message.

Comment: If my suspicion is correct, there are several things you could do to remove those "annoying" debug statements - such as removing the `debug` gem from the project, or [changing the log level to INFO](https://github.com/ruby/debug#configuration-list).

Comment: You're correct @TomLord I removed the debug gem from my Gemfile and it no longer logs those debug statements. Thanks!

Comment: Removing `debug` from the Gemfile as Tom Lord suggests worked for me.

Comment: ... but then how do you debug your application? :D

Comment: @emptywalls I ended up just keeping debug in the Gemfile, they're just harmless debug statements.